# A word to describe a negative event that may take place in the future

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word ( a compound word or phrase would be acceptable) that describes a negative event that may take place in the future. However, I was unable to find such a word in the prominent online thesaurus or dictionary.

For instance, this year a number of countries the world over were forced to impose lock downs to stop the spread of the ongoing corona virus pandemic.  **What word can be used to describe a negative event like the corona virus pandemic that may occur in the future?**

**Sample Sentence**: *A _ like the 2020 corona virus pandemic might occur in the future.*

So I can fill that blank with the words negative event. *A negative event like the 2020 corona virus pandemic might occur in the future*.

In place of the words *negative event* I am looking for a word that describes such an event that might occur in the future.

Comment: Synonyms of 'catastrophe' / 'disaster' already abound on ELU. Adding 'future' / 'future possible' doesn't make this a new request.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Hi, in my question I was referring to a prospective event that may take place in the future. If the event has already taken place words like catastrophe, disaster can be used. However, my question was related to a negative event that may take place in the future.

Comment: There is no reason to suppose that catastrophe/disaster is limited to any time past, present, or future.

Comment: The trouble is that you are getting (and will doubtless get more if the question is re-opened) answers that are merely hypernyms, synonyms of 'disaster' / 'catastrophe' / 'tragedy'. This treats the question as one too basic for ELU. // I strongly doubt there are any words for 'possible future catastrophe', and the people voting to re-open should not do so unless they have one in mind. They can prove this in a 'comment'.

Comment: If catastrophe/disaster is not limited to any time past, present, or future then what would be a specific word to describe a potential upcoming catastrophe?

Comment: Actually, so far there is just one answer. Future answers could well provide the correct answer. Answers maybe correct or incorrect. But is there any ELU rule that states number of answers should be restricted? If not, keeping this answer open should not be an issue. Clearly, this question is not a duplicate because a similar question that asks for a term to describe a potential future catastrophe has not yet been asked.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the term ***[catastrophe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/catastrophe):***

> a sudden event that causes very great trouble or destruction:

> - They were warned of the ecological catastrophe to come.

(Cambridge Dictionary )

> A  *catastrophe*  like the 2020 corona virus pandemic might occur in the future.